# Maven Jar Plug-In weird error NoClassDefFoundError: javá/nio/fiìe/FileStore

Tags: java, maven, build, java-7, noclassdeffounderror

The following error is received when trying to install a component.

What makes it weird is that the cause seems to be: `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javá/nio/fiìe/FileStore` written with those accents. Both `java -version` and `javac -version` return version 7 so `FileStore` class should be there, but in a package without those accents. I have deleted all `~/m2` without any success. As it can be seen in logs, version 2.3.2 from jar plug-in is used; no configuration is set in `pom.xml` for this plug-in, only `artifactId`, `groupId` and `version`.

The locale is en_US and encoding is UTF-8 according to the first part of Maven stacktrace with `-X`:

```
Apache Maven 3.0.4
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_40, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /x/s/jdk1.7.0_40/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.2.0-54-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

The last part of the trace, when called with `-X` is:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 18.515s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Nov 18 14:17:50 EET 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 23M/128M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2:jar (default-jar) on project common: Execution default-jar of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2:jar failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2:jar: javá/nio/fiìe/FileStore
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/home/dev/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/2.3.2/maven-jar-plugin-2.3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/home/dev/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/home/dev/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-archiver/2.4.2/maven-archiver-2.4.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/home/dev/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.13/plexus-interpolation-1.13.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/home/dev/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/2.0.1/plexus-archiver-2.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/home/dev/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/2.0.1/plexus-io-2.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/home/dev/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.1/commons-lang-2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/home/dev/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0/plexus-utils-3.0.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2:jar (default-jar) on project common: Execution default-jar of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2:jar failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2:jar: javá/nio/fiìe/FileStore
-----------------------------------------------------
realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2
strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
urls[0] = file:/home/dev/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/2.3.2/maven-jar-plugin-2.3.2.jar
urls[1] = file:/home/dev/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar
urls[2] = file:/home/dev/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-archiver/2.4.2/maven-archiver-2.4.2.jar
urls[3] = file:/home/dev/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.13/plexus-interpolation-1.13.jar
urls[4] = file:/home/dev/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/2.0.1/plexus-archiver-2.0.1.jar
urls[5] = file:/home/dev/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/2.0.1/plexus-io-2.0.1.jar
urls[6] = file:/home/dev/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.1/commons-lang-2.1.jar
urls[7] = file:/home/dev/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0/plexus-utils-3.0.jar
Number of foreign imports: 1
import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

-----------------------------------------------------

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:225)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-jar of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2:jar failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2:jar: javá/nio/fiìe/FileStore
-----------------------------------------------------
realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2
strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
urls[0] = file:/home/dev/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/2.3.2/maven-jar-plugin-2.3.2.jar
urls[1] = file:/home/dev/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar
urls[2] = file:/home/dev/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-archiver/2.4.2/maven-archiver-2.4.2.jar
urls[3] = file:/home/dev/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.13/plexus-interpolation-1.13.jar
urls[4] = file:/home/dev/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/2.0.1/plexus-archiver-2.0.1.jar
urls[5] = file:/home/dev/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/2.0.1/plexus-io-2.0.1.jar
urls[6] = file:/home/dev/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.1/commons-lang-2.1.jar
urls[7] = file:/home/dev/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0/plexus-utils-3.0.jar
Number of foreign imports: 1
import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

-----------------------------------------------------

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:127)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginContainerException: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2:jar: javá/nio/fiìe/FileStore
-----------------------------------------------------
realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2
strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
urls[0] = file:/home/dev/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/2.3.2/maven-jar-plugin-2.3.2.jar
urls[1] = file:/home/dev/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar
urls[2] = file:/home/dev/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-archiver/2.4.2/maven-archiver-2.4.2.jar
urls[3] = file:/home/dev/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.13/plexus-interpolation-1.13.jar
urls[4] = file:/home/dev/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/2.0.1/plexus-archiver-2.0.1.jar
urls[5] = file:/home/dev/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/2.0.1/plexus-io-2.0.1.jar
urls[6] = file:/home/dev/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.1/commons-lang-2.1.jar
urls[7] = file:/home/dev/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0/plexus-utils-3.0.jar
Number of foreign imports: 1
import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

-----------------------------------------------------

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:125)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javá/nio/fiìe/FileStore
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2521)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2764)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1653)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.components.io.attributes.Java7Reflector.<clinit>(Java7Reflector.java:86)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.components.io.attributes.PlexusIoResourceAttributeUtils.getFileAttributesByPath(PlexusIoResourceAttributeUtils.java:222)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.components.io.attributes.PlexusIoResourceAttributeUtils.getFileAttributes(PlexusIoResourceAttributeUtils.java:172)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.ArchiveEntry.createFileEntry(ArchiveEntry.java:158)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver.addFile(AbstractArchiver.java:382)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver.addFile(AbstractArchiver.java:297)
    at org.apache.maven.archiver.MavenArchiver.createArchive(MavenArchiver.java:487)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.jar.AbstractJarMojo.createArchive(AbstractJarMojo.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.jar.AbstractJarMojo.execute(AbstractJarMojo.java:235)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    ... 20 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either have defective memory or one of the JARs on your hard disk got corrupte.

Delete `/home/dev/.m2/repository` and try again.

If that doesn't solve the issues, run a memory test. If that shows something, then repair the PC. If it doesn't show anything, replace the PC - memory tests don't always find a flaw. If they find something, you can be sure there is a problem. If they find nothing, you simply don't know because a certain access pattern could cause the problem.

Comment: I've deleted everything under `~/.m2/repository` without success. Now I've deleted it again and same results; the code is running in a virtual machine so first I'll ask to be reinstalled.

Comment: Maybe the JAR got corrupted elsewhere. Do you have a company repository? Also try to isolate which JAR is bad: Run the code in a debugger and set a breakpoint for `NoClassDefFoundError`

Answer (score 1):

try first to ensure there is no problem with your JDK installation itself. If the compilation/run fails then reinstall your JDK.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileStore fs = Files.getFileStore(Paths.get(".", "."));
        System.out.println(fs);
    }
}
```